# URL rewriting without redirection

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how I am able to change the URL without redirecting the page. For example, soundcloud.com will not reload the page when you select a new song but the url changes to "soundcloud.com/AUTHOR/NAME". I would really like to know how this is possible, how they have done it.

So far I know that with javascript you are able to rewrite only the values after # in a URL. With .htaccess rewrite rules, I am not sure you can specify that the page shouldn't reload.

Can anyone guide me on the path to figuring out where to start? Thank you very much!

Comment: Check soundcloud api: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/

Comment: You can do a search before asking a question. It prevents duplicates!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

> Suppose **mozilla.org/foo.html** executes the following JavaScript:
>   var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
>   history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
>
> This will cause the URL bar to display 
>   **mozilla.org/bar.html**, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

This only works with HTML5 browsers.

More discussion: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)